# What is the meaning of "sleep dep"?

Tags: abbreviations

[image: Cartoon of woman saying "Okay, brain, we're just going to write this one off to sleep dep, starvation and being unable to afford all my meds"]

What does "dep" mean here? I found some variants, but can't be sure which of them the right one.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleep_deprivation

Comment: Autocomplete in a popular search engine will suggest "Sleep deprivation" (along with "Sleep depression") which should allow you to check whether it could be relevant here.

Answer (score 1):

"Dep" is an abbreviation for "deprivation". 
The girl in the image is trying to use "[sleep deprivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleep_deprivation)":

> Sleep deprivation is the condition of not having enough sleep; it can be either chronic or acute. A chronic sleep-restricted state can cause fatigue, daytime sleepiness, clumsiness and weight loss or weight gain.

[Wikipedia]

Comment: Trying to use? I'd say she's *blaming* sleep deprivation for her current situation (whatever that is in the context of the comic).

Comment: @TRiG I meant she's trying to use the word. Sorry for the ambiguous verb I used